# Algorithm to find a combination of sets with most elements

Tags: algorithm

Suppose there are m(m<100) sets and elements are limited to 1-n(n<100). I am looking for an algorithm to find a combination of sets that cover the most elements and any two sets have no intersection.

**Example:**

**Input:** `[{1,2,3},{2,4},{3,5}]`

**Output:** `[{2,4},{3,5}]`

If there is a solution better than O(2^m)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me restate the problem as I understand it.

You have a collection of sets.  You'd like to find a subcollection where no two sets intersect, whose union is as big as possible.

This optimization problem is an NP-hard problem, and therefore every known algorithm is exponential in `m`.  This can be seen by restricting to the special case where every set has 3 elements.  That is the [3-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching) problem.  The decision variant is, "Find whether you can cover at least `k` elements."  The decision variant was on Karp's original list of 21 NP-complete problems.

Why is the optimization version NP-hard and decision version NP-complete?  That is because there is no easy way to verify that a claimed optimal set of subsets is in fact optimal.  But it is easy to verify that a collection of disjoint subsets that covers at least `k` elements is what you claim.